# psql: Issue with dumping file (Access Denied)

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-9.6

I recently posted about trying to export a database from pgAdmin. I am working on a windows machine and postgresql 9.6.

I got to a point where I can successfully dump a database from the command line (I get all of the printout of the data from each table), but am running into issues with saving the file. Curious if I could get input into what I might be doing incorrectly.

Command Line: Dump all - prints out data

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin>pg_dump   postgresql://postgres:password@127.0.0.1:5432/Housing_DB
```

or

Database: dump all a bit quicker

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin>pg_dump -U postgres -W -F t Housing_DB
```

Both provide the following output (at the end):
[image]

However, when I try to store into a specific spot, I get an error. Here is what I try:

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin>pg_dump postgresql://postgres:password@127.0.0.1:5432/Housing_DB > C:\sample.out
```

Error is: **Access is Denied**

**Questions:**

1) My assumption is that I can only save this file in certain locations, but I am not sure how to find this information out. I have tried storing on desktop, within the bin for PostgreSQL, and then on C:\, but I am very unfamiliar with storage locations in general.

2) I also could not figure how to use psql to do this - I am able to connect over to the database I wish to backup/dump, but could not use "pg_dump" when using the psql command line.

Thanks for reading and assisting.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to resolve this all I needed to do was run the command prompt as admin.

So, when opening command prompt I did right click "Run as administrator", and from there I was able to dump and save file where i wanted.

Let me know if I should just delete this question, thanks!